# How to convert a Byte into an Int in C#

Tags: c#

I converted a music file into a `byte`, and now I need to know how to convert a `byte` into an `int`.

I've tried the following, but it failed:

```
BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 0);
```

Comment: ALSO IF YOU GUYS HAVE GOOD WAYS TO CONVERT A MUSIC FILE INTO A BYTE I TRIED THIS

Comment: int intValue = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            try { 
            byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(intBytes);
            byte[] result = intBytes;
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblVoice(flbVoice) VALUE (intBytes)");

Comment: BitConverter.ToInt32 will look at 4 bytes. Does `array` have 4 bytes?

Comment: Welcome to SO; you could read something on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, please do not post comments to your question, but edit the question

Comment: Wait, let me see if I understand this... You converted a *music* file into a `byte` array, and want to convert that into a single number?  What are you honestly expecting as an outcome for this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what "failed" means: did it not compile? Did it throw and exception? If so, what was the full message of the exception?

In any case, `BitConverter.ToInt32` looks at exactly 4 bytes and will throw an exception if your `array` has less than 4 bytes.

If you want to convert a single byte to an int, just assign it. It will be implicitly casted.

```
byte myByte = 0;
int myInt = myByte;
```

Comment: my project is to take a music file that the user choses from a list box and convert it into a byte

Comment: which i have done so i am now working on grabing the byte from the sever and converting it back to a music file

Comment: Then you can look at [File.WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) which will allow you to write a byte array to a file.

Comment: thank you for your input